# Django - See the foreignkey object's details in admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I have a model like below;

```
class Lecturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name=u'Eğitmenin Adı')
    tc_kimlik_no = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Eğitmenin TC Kimlik Numarası')
    sertifika_no = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name=u'Eğitmenin sertifika numarası')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Certificate(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name=u'Adı ve Soyadı')
       tc_kimlik = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="TC Kimlik No")
       sertifika_no = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Sertifika No")
       egitim_tarihi = models.DateField(verbose_name='Eğitim Tarihi')
       hangi_egitim = models.ManyToManyField(Egitim,verbose_name="Hangi Eğitimi aldı?")
       nerde_verildi = models.ForeignKey(City,verbose_name="Eğitim Nerde Verildi")
       lecturer = models.ForeignKey(Lecturer,verbose_name="Eğitmen")
```

But in the admin panel when **lecturer** object is selected in the **Certificate** admin form, i want to see the other details of lecturer other than unicode like "tc_kimlik_no and sertifika_no". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess of your requirement, If you want to show the other things just add them in your `unicode` method also:

```
class Lecturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name=u'Eğitmenin Adı')
    tc_kimlik_no = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Eğitmenin TC Kimlik Numarası')
    sertifika_no = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name=u'Eğitmenin sertifika numarası')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Name: %s, Kimlik: %s, Sertifika: %s' % (
            self.name, str(self.tc_kimlik_no), self.sertifika_no)
```

Is that what you wanted?